# How do I plot a gigantic function easily on Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I need to graph a gigantic function on Mathematica, that has other functions inside it and some constants with preassigned values that come up a lot! For example:

W = QbBesselK...., in which Q is an equation like Q = x*b + ..., and b has a said value.

Is there a way to write this as

Being b = 10 and Q = x*b + ...,

Plot[QbBesselK]?

I'm new to Wolfram Mathematica and this would help me a lot.

Example of what I want to do:

```
//Nc, alpha, b, Bcgc, xo, x and lambda are constants and would be defined as 

Nc = 1
alpha = 2
b = 3
Bcgc = 4
xo = 5
x = 6
lambda = 7


//k is the variable

Qs = (xo/x)^(lambda/2) * e^(-b²/2*Bcgc) >> an equation used in W


W = Nc/pi*alpha {(b²/2*(Bcgc)²Qs³)[2*Qs*BesselK[0,k/Qs] - k*BesselK[1,k/Qs]] + BesselK[0,k/Qs]/2*Bcgc*Qs² - (2*k²*BesselK[1,k/Qs)/k*Qs} >> defining W

Plot[W, {k, 0, 1}] >> and then plotting
```

Comment: Can you explain this notation in more detail: `QbBesselK`? It's not clear to me what you're trying to plot. Also, is your question more about how to plot things (since you said you're new to Mathematica), or are you comfortable plotting simple things and you're just out of your depth with something complicated?

Comment: Like, is that just a product of expressions:`Q * b * BesselK[...]`?

Comment: Please post your code, so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: "Is there a way to write this as Being..." - sounds like a job for `Module[]` or `With[]`, depending on what you're doing. Showing us what you actually have will help us help you.

Comment: `Plot[W, {x, 0, 2}]` would probably work, to plot `W` for `0 <= x <= 2`, if things are as the snippets of code suggest. If it doesn't work, you'll need to post the complete code.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. `gigantic` is not a well-defned word in mathematics. I would recommend that you to load the code that generated this function that needs to be plotted. You can visit the [help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help) page for this stack site as well as take the site [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). For learning Mathematica, the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a valuable resource.

Comment: @lericr this plot is part of my research, i'm just trying to do it in a less complicated manner

Comment: @E.Chan-López I'll post it correctly in just a few minutes, but to clear it out i'm trying to define some parts of the equation before I plot the role thing, like you would do in a C program for example

Comment: @E.Chan-López I edited the post with my equation

Comment: @Syed for gigantic i just meant is a long equation

Comment: Note that you're still missing the definition for `lambda`.

Comment: All built-in functions and constants start with a capital letter. `e` should be `E`, `pi` should be `Pi`. You cannot use `List` brackets `{ }` or function brackets `[ ]` in place of parentheses `( )` [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720) When posting code here, convert it to `InputForm` prior to copy and paste.

Comment: Comments in Mathematica code are set off in this fashion `(* This is a comment *)`

Answer (score 3):

Based on what I'm seeing in your definitions, the main hurdle to get over is syntax. Then you need to know how to reference built-in constants. After that, I'd suggest defining a function, although it's not strictly necessary.

If we were to have a function for your W (which I'll call `functionW` to avoid a single, capital letter as a symbol name), then the plot expression would look like this:

```
Plot[functionW[k], {k, 0, 1}]
```

This leads to syntax. The square brackets, `[]`, are used for function application. They cannot be used to change precedence in arithmetic expressions--they are reserved for just function application.

The curly brackets, `{}`, are used to create lists. They are reserved for this, and cannot be used for precedence.

Now we can fix the syntax in your W expression and use the typical function-defining pattern:

```
functionW[k_] := 
  Nc/Pi*alpha ((b^2/2*Bcgc^2 Qs^2) (2*Qs*BesselK[0, k/Qs] - k*BesselK[1, k/Qs]) + BesselK[0, k/Qs]/2*Bcgc*Qs^2 - (2*k^2*BesselK[1, k/Qs]/k*Qs))
```

I've done my best to determine the correct precedence, but you should definitely check this to make sure it matches what you intended.

Notice that `Pi` is capitalized. Built in symbols are capitalized. So, you also need to fix Euler's constant in `Qs`:

```
Qs = (xo/x)^(lambda/2)*E^(-b^2/2*Bcgc)
```

Again, you need to check that this matches what you actually intended. You might want to add in parentheses explicitly until you're confident in the precedence of operations.

Your simple constants are fine, but you might want to use `;` between them so that you don't litter your notebook with unnecessary outputs:

```
Nc = 1;
alpha = 2;
b = 3;
Bcgc = 4;
xo = 5;
x = 6;
lambda = 7;
```

Comment: thank you so much, this helped a lot